# How to limit linear velocity in Godot rigid bodies?

Tags: godot, godot4

I use `apply_central_force` in a top-down 2D car game to move a car. I had to limit the linear velocity separately in `_integrate_forces` and that causes a bouncing or elasticity when hitting a wall. Any ideas if there's something better to do?

Would I've to use a `CharacterBody2D` instead?

---

The car moves to the *directional* you press. It rotates to the direction you go. The issue is that when the car performs a drift of around 180º degrees in a wall, it gets a slight bounce.

---

I'm using a constant angular velocity for tweening the car's rotation to the direction (i.e. *up*, *up-left*, left_ and so on).

Comment: Using `_integrate_forces` is what comes to mind, I do not know about the bouncing/elasticity you mention... However, I'm aware of a fix for the velocity in `_integrate_forces` that was merged for Godot 4.2 (currently in dev builds), could you check if it fixes the problem?

Comment: @Theraot Just tried it, but I guess it's not a Godot bug really, it's just the way I'm tweening the rotation.